# Why is my Worksheet_Change event not working for copy, paste unique values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code where a list of numbers in a column need to paste into another column without any duplicates. This works in a regular sub(), but when I try to do this in a Worksheet_Change, it does not execute. Nothing changes on the sheet. I need the code to execute automatically if I change values on the list.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B14").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Range("C3"), _
    Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Asks for a macro name, i.e. an indication that the code did not compile.

Comment: "Does not work" as in, freezes/crashes Excel completely? As if modifying the sheet while handling an event that Excel fires when a sheet is modified, would be infinitely re-entering the handler? Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top, `= True` at the bottom.

Comment: If the code runs, then it compiles. Code that can't compile, can't run at all.

Comment: Its not working as intended. Even with adding Application.EnableEvents...

Comment: We're going to need to have a much clearer description of exactly what "not working" means in order to help. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: So - if I click run, it is not copying and pasting into the intended cell. It does not execute.

Comment: Select the `ActiveSheet.Range(...)` instruction, press F9. There should be a red dot in the left margin of the editor now - that's called a "breakpoint". Go to your sheet, modify anything. If the VBE pops up with the line with the breakpoint is highlighted in bright yellow, your code does execute. `Worksheet_Change` is in the code-behind of one specific worksheet, and will only run when *that sheet* is modified. Is in in the code-behind of the *correct* sheet module? Or do you need it to run regardless of what sheet is modified in `ThisWorkbook`? Or is it in *whatever workbook is active*?

Comment: By doing that, I got the message saying "Breakpoint not allowed on this line".

Comment: Also - it is on the correct sheet - for example if enter the code in a simple Private Sub ()...Exit Sub, the code executes as intended aka copies and pastes into a new column without duplicates.

Comment: A breakpoint can be toggled on any executable line of code. Make sure you're on an executable statement (not Dim, not Sub)

Comment: I clicked on the line as you suggested - ActiveSheet.Range... so the second line on the code above. I was wondering maybe I would have to enter if statements? I've noticed from googling that if statements are common on Worksheet_Change.

Comment: Do you have enable events on?

Comment: yes! As suggested by Mathieu. Please try this code on a sample set of numbers. The code runs without a worksheet_change - but it does not work with it.

Comment: Well if you put ```application.enableevents``` inside an event, but your events are turned off, then they aren't going to turn back on because events aren't being executed. The code works on my end.

Comment: can you copy and paste it on here? I keep trying but it does not seem to do anything on my worksheet so I might have just entered it in a weird order.

Comment: create a sub that only contains ```application.enableevents = True``` and run that. Then try and make a change on your sheet.

Comment: Sub runevent()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub.....


This did not seem to do anything to my worksheet.

Comment: It won't make a change it just turns event handling back on if it was disabled. Allowing your worksheet_change sub to run.

Comment: Yes - so I added a sub with only the application.enableevents = True. And then I also have my Worksheet Change right underneath. However, by doing this, there was no change to my worksheet. I'm not sure if I wrote it correctly.

Comment: As was already said, `Application.EnableEvents = True` does not change your worksheet. It makes the `Worksheet_Change` handler be invoked when the sheet is later modified. You need `Application.EnableEvents` to be `True` for the event handler to be allowed to run, AND you need to toggle it off at the beginning and back on at the end, like my very first comment said, otherwise your handler will be re-entrant and that will blow up.

Comment: I tried doing that which did not invoke the change that I had wanted on my worksheet... as was already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is one of a few things, most of which have been covered in the comments.

1. Enable Events must be on.

```
Sub RunEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
end sub
```

2. You need the Worksheet_Change sub in the proper Sheet Module

   Blue arrow is where it needs to be (or whatever your sheet is called)

   Red arrow is point 1.

   Place `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of your change event and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the bottom.

[image]

3. Make the changes, the code you gave relies on B2 having data, and will create a duplicate if you have two of whatever is in B2. You can see what I mean in the gif.

[image]

Comment: Kudos for taking the time to do this. Note literally all of it was covered in the comments - I guess an animated gif is worth a thousand words ;-)

Comment: Actually - "Place Application.EnableEvents = False at the top of your change event" was not on the code above and still unanswered but I rather not continue this discussion and they also took the time to write this out which is what I was asking for.

Comment: @BrowniesAtNight Yeah sorry I took the screenshot and forgot to add it in. Whenever you do anything in event handling you need to turn events off for the duration otherwise you can create an endless cycle of events since it is making changes, thus triggering the on change event.